# JSONP from URL returns nothing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, jsonp

Hi ive been reading for almost 1week about json.

```
$.getJSON( 'accounts.json', function(data ) {
$('#try1').append("<option value='0' name='idsel'>Select Outlet</option>");
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
$('#try1').append("<option value='" + item.outlet_group_id + "'>" + item.outlet_group_name + " : " + item.outlet_group_code + "</option>");
});
});
```

i have this script that works fine, but when i load it on the url it doesnt appear
the url is this http://nutri.de.imerchmedia.com/services/accounts

Also i have tried jsonp, i came up with this

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://nutri.de.imerchmedia.com/services/accounts',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(data1){
$.each(data, function (k,v) {
console.log(data1);
$('#form').append(k + ':' + v);
});
}
});
```

i wonder is it me or it is the host?

any help would be much appreciated.
also feel free to try extracting the data thru the link.

Comment: are you getting any errors?  Any data? Have you checked using firebug?  Is this a same-origin-policy restriction? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: The URL returns JSON, not JSONP, so you cannot use JSONP. Since it is an external domain, you cannot use Ajax, unless the server supports CORS.

Comment: its htmlrequest and sameoriginpolicy restriction, but i think i already did try everything and i still can't make it to work

Comment: @FelixKling If its json it should work on my first script right? since my first script reads a saved json file that is exactly the link's content

Comment: No, it doesn't because you are accessing an external domain. You cannot load *any* data from an external domain via Ajax unless it has CORS enabled. JSONP is actually not Ajax, it works by dynamically adding a `<script>` element.

Comment: So in conclusion, i cannot extract the data from the site using ajax/jquery unless they allow cross origin header. Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a Cross-Origin issue. You can't load json into your website from another domain without their permission. Their server must add a Cross-Origin-Allow header to the file it sends you that tells the browser it's ok. It doesn't look like http://nutri.de.imerchmedia.com/services/accounts is sending that header. So you won't be able to use it.

Jsonp is a format that people are using to get around the json cross origin restrictions. Whether or not a server will send jsonp or just json is dependent on the server configuration and it doesn't look like imerchmedia has taken the steps to enable serving jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that URL you provided, there is no `callback` wrapper for JSONP to work. JSONP requires the output of a regular JSON data structure to be "wrapped" in a function on your page. Normally jQuery does this for you, so you would call your service with:

```
http://nutri.de.imerchmedia.com/services/accounts?callback=foobar
```

and you would be expected to have a `function foobar (data) {...}` on the page. Again, jQuery creates this function for you, but your service would need to wrap the response data like so:

```
foobar('jsontoreturnhere...')
```

### However

**Given that data** and your example code, I have a copy of it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfay/jCqwp/

I cannot do the Ajax call on jsfiddle, so I'm only simulating the internal part of your function. I suspect that is doing what you want, so I think it's probably either:

- your `#try1` selector is wrong/misspelled
- make sure you are using a `<select id='try1'>`

gl
Aaron